# Put Inset beyond plot range

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, inset

I want to put an inset `(a)` further downward (**roughly the same height as the BarLegend**). However, the following code doesn't seem to allow that. Can one do it someway?

```
data = Table[
   Sin[x] Cos[y] + 0.05 x y, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
labellst = {"(a)", {0.15, 0.03}};
insetlst = Inset[Style[#[[1]], Large], ImageScaled[#[[2]]]] &@labellst;
MatrixPlot[data, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  Epilog -> insetlst, LabelStyle -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If needed, play with parameters.

```
labelSize = 30;
labelPos = {0.1, -0.2};
legendPos = {0.5, -0.1};
data = Table[
   Sin[x] Cos[y] + 0.05 x y, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
MatrixPlot[data, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Scaled[legendPos]], 
 LabelStyle -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 Epilog -> Text[Style["(a)", labelSize], Scaled[labelPos]]]
```

[image]

Comment: It works with `MatrixPlot` but does not with `ListContourPlot` or `ListDensityPlot`

Comment: Adding `PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> {{20, 1}, {60, 1}}`  fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The sub-labeling of the plots is realized bad enough in MMA.
I guess, the simplest way is using `Overlay`:

```
Overlay[
 {ContourPlot[Sin[x y^2], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -3, 3},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   ContourStyle -> None,
   ImageSize -> 600,
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}, 10, 
      LegendMarkerSize -> 350], Below]],
  Graphics[{Text[Style["a)", 14, Bold], Scaled@{0, 0}]}, 
   ImageSize -> {350, 350}]}
 ]
```

[image]

Playing with `ImageSize` of the `Graphics` layer one can obtain the desired position of the label.

Answer (score 3):

***To have the label at the same vertical position as the legend:***

**1.** Inject the label into the legend using the option [`LegendFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendFunction.html) in `BarLegend`:

```
MatrixPlot[data, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, 
      LegendFunction -> (Row[{Style[labellst[[1]], Large], #}] &)], 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, LabelStyle -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

**2.** Add the label as a legend specifying *multiple* legends in `PlotLegends`:

```
MatrixPlot[data, 
 PlotLegends -> Thread[Placed[{Style[labellst[[1]], Large], Automatic}, Below]], 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, LabelStyle -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

You can have more precise positioning using the $\{\{e_x,e_y\},\{l_x, l_y\}\}$ form instead of symbolic positions in `Placed`:

```
positions = {{{.5, -.1}, {.5, .5}}, {{.15, -.1}, {.5, .5}}};

MatrixPlot[data, 
 PlotLegends -> Thread[Placed[{Automatic, Style[labellst[[1]], Large]}, positions]],
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, LabelStyle -> Medium, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

**3.**  Post-process `MatrixPlot` output to insert the label to the left of the legend:

```
MatrixPlot[data, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
   LabelStyle -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1/2] /. 
 Placed[lg_, a__] :> Placed[Row[{Style[labellst[[1]], Large], lg}], a]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a direct way using `LegendLabel`

```
data = Table[
   Sin[x] Cos[y] + 0.05 x y, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
MatrixPlot[data,PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 280, 
    LegendLabel -> Placed[Style[Text["(a)"], Red, FontSize -> 24], Left]], Bottom], 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]